# Add label to right of button

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I add dynamically add buttons to a webpage as follows:

```
$('#Container').empty();
for (i = 0; i < l; i++) 
{
     $('#Container').append($('<button id="but'+(i+1)+'" type="button" value="'+i+'">?</button>'));
}
$('#Container').trigger('create');
```

The container is defined as follows:

```
<div data-role="content" id = "Container">
```

How can I add a label to the right of each button?

I tried:

```
$('#Container').empty();
for (i = 0; i < l; i++) 
{
     $('#Container').append($('<button id="but'+(i+1)+'" type="button" value="'+i+'">?</button>'));
     $('#Container').last().after($('<label>Hello</label>'));
}
$('#Container').trigger('create');
```

but this appends all the labels to the end.

Comment: What do you want the labels to say? "Add" or the value of i  ?

Comment: @Last1Here I will be looking up a value in an array based on the value of i

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#Container').empty();

for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
   $('#Container').append($('<button id="but' + (i + 1) + '" type="button" value="' + i + '">?</button>'));
   $('#Container').append($('<span><label>Hello</label></span><br/>'));
}
$('#Container').trigger('create');
```

Comment: Tried this on my Mac with Firefox and the labels appeared under the buttons. Note that I'm using Jquery-mobile.

Comment: I'm using chrome on windows, where it works ok, well I don't have a mac or proper mobile environment to test with so I can't help you much further. If I was you though I'd make the ui in plain html until it works and then build it dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done a jQuery Mobile question in a while.

Working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/rfmhxdeh/

#### JavaScript

```
$('#Container').empty();
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    $('#Container').append($('<div class="custom-btn-container"><button id="but' + (i + 1) + '" type="button" value="' + i + ' class="custom-btn"">?</button><label>Hello</label></div>'));
}
$('#Container').trigger('create');
```

#### CSS

```
.custom-btn-container {
    display: flex; /* or inline-flex */
}

.custom-btn-container button {
    margin: 0 2% 20px;
}

.custom-btn-container label {
    line-height: 50px;
}
```

Magic word in this example is:

```
display: flex;
```

My advice read about it.